# How to configure node-mysql?

Tags: user-interface, node.js, configuration, node-mysql

I've found a lot of tutorials explaining how to install "node-mysql" (basically: "npm install mysql" and that's it) and others explaining how to make queries but nothing in-between.

I mean: with no GUI, how do you configure node-mysql (Mysql login, Mysql password, first table,..) before using it?

OR: How to install a GUI to access node-mysql for edition (which would solve problem 1)?

I tried "Mysql Workbench" via its wizard but I get a "Cannot connect to Database Server" while the host and the port are ok. I searched the "MySQL Workbench" website but there's nothing about node-mysql.

Node-Mysql seems to be the first choice when it comes to use mysql with node.js but, surprisingly, there's absolutely nothing about my issues, anywhere.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to configure node-mysql itself, you need to learn [how to add users to mysql database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html).

if you already have existing user, node-mysql client is very straightforward to use:

```
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'someusername',
  password: 'somepassword',
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey. First of all, I don't have any existing user as I just installed node-mysql. Now, about your script: Where do I have to put it? Obviously I will not create a Mysql admin login, password each time I execute the node.js server file. And what about creating a database and a table and columns and types... In PHPMyAdmin (I have a php background), at the beginning of any project, I create all those things via a GUI. Doing otherwise may seem trivial but for me, it's a no man's land. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Forgot to mention: tried your link which should be helpful but none of the shell commands related to mysql seem to work for me. i.e.:"mysql --user=root mysql" etc.. All I get is "command not found" (don't know if it helps but the only mysql folder I found on my Mac is there:"users/me/node_modules/mysql/")

Comment: do you use local mysql server?

Comment: Yes. For testing purposes. FYI: I'm testing node.js as php/ajax are not ideal for instant messaging. I installed node.js, now.js, express.js with no issue so far. I tried to use mongoDB (successfully) but it doesn't fit my needs as I really need to make relations between tables (and I have some experience with mysql queries. Learning a completely different way to manage data, among the rest, would be overwhelming for me). I can imagine how basic it is but I'm just stuck.

Comment: if you have local installation of mysql server then you most likely have command line client called `mysql`. Can you start it from command line? on mac it's usually a /usr/local/bin/mysql (homebrew and package from mysql.com default location)

Comment: Thanks Andrey. It seems, from what you say that installing node-mysql doesn't install mysql itself (didn't know that and lot of blogs assume that it does, according to their tutorials), so I did what you say: "brew install mysql". Now it's definitely there, exactly where you said it would be but when I launch it trough "mysql" or "/usr/local/bin/mysql " command, here's what I get: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)". I tried to reach this "/tmp" folder and there it is with a bunch of files and folders but nothing related to mysql...

Comment: what is the output of `ps ax | grep mysqld` (do you have server started?)